# How to use php sessions in xslt?

Tags: php, xslt, session

How do I use php sessions in XSLT for example for making a shopping cart for a webshop?

A user can browse the site and click "Add to cart" on several items. Each item should then be stored in a session variable. The user can at all time view the items selected by clicking "View cart".

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly do you want to achive? Creating a shopping cart is rather generic...

Comment: Really unsure what you are trying to achieve.  Do you want the XML data in the session?  (Why would you do this?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using XSLT from within PHP, you can pass parameters to it by [`XSLTProcessor::setParameter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php). You'll have to declare that parameter in XSL with

```
<xsl:param name="«param name»"/>
```

For example...

PHP:

```
// $xsl, $xml -- DOMDocument objects
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
$proc->setParameter(''/*default namespace*/, 'test_param', $aValue);
$proc->setParameter('', 'session_name', session_name());
$proc->setParameter('', 'session_id', session_id());
echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="test_param"/>
    <xsl:param name="session_name"/>
    <xsl:param name="session_id"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <p>Your test parameter is: <xsl:value-of select="$test_param"/></p>
        <p>Your session name is: <xsl:value-of select="$session_name"/></p>
        <p>Your session ID is: <xsl:value-of select="$session_id"/></p>
        <p>
         <a>
          <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('http://example.com/index.php?',$session_name,'=',$session_id)"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          Link with session
        </a>
       </p> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're probably calling the xslt processor on some XML, why don't you just add the session data to that xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Long since answered but for the record...

Get session variables directly from within the xsl:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?php echo 'SESSION Name: ' . $_SESSION['session_name']; ?&gt;</xsl:text>
```

When doing the transform, instead of echo'ing the transformation, include it:

```
$output_file = 'new_file.php';
$xslt->transformToUri( $xml_dom,  $output_file);
include ('new_file.php');
```